Proof of the principle of explosion
The Wikipedia page uses the following proof for the statement:
$$\begin{align}(1)&\ P & \text{(Premise)}\\ (2)&\ \neg P & \text{(Premise)}\\ (3)&\ P\lor Q & \text{(Disjunction)}\\ (4)&\ Q & \text{(Disj. sill.)}\end{align}$$
which I have no trouble understanding. The issues are two to me:

this proof specifically deals with contradictions, not any false proposition;
I could prove the same thing using the definition of $P\to Q$ as $\neg P\lor Q$, which would make the implication true whenever $\neg P$, not only when $P$ is a contradiction

I tried to do some research about it, and from what I was able to grasp my question is dumb, I'm pretty sure about that. I mean that there is probably something important that I am missing (my knowledge of logic is very shallow). So if someone can enlighten me I will be grateful.

$P$ and $\neg P$ are interchangeable. A contradiction is any always-false statement, here the contradiction $P\wedge \neg P$ can be considered as a premise or conjunction of premises 1,2.

@DavidP yes, I understand that. My main concern was the second point in my question.

it's not even clear what your question is. try articulating your confusion as a question and adding that question to your OP

This would work if, instead of provisional assumptions (i.e. premises), lines 1 and 2 were axioms. Then any proposition Q would indeed be a theorem. As it stands, your proof is incomplete with your provisional assumptions not being discharged. (See my answer)

$P\implies P$ is true. Also, $A\implies A.$

Re the second point in your question, the proof still holds.
We have (1) $P$ and (2) $¬P$ as assumptions.
Instead of deriving (3) $P \lor Q$ from (1) by Disjunction introduction (aka: Addition), we have to use the tautology (3) $¬P → (P → Q)$ from which, using Modus Ponens, we get (4) $P → Q$ and then (5) $Q$.
Of course, if you have the Material implication rule: $\lnot P \to Q \equiv P \lor Q$, you can use it to derive $\lnot P \to Q$ from your (3) and then conclude with $Q$ using (2) and MP.



this proof specifically deals with contradictions, not any false proposition;


The proof deals with when both a proposition and its negation are assumed true.


I could prove the same thing using the definition of P→Q
as ¬P∨Q,


How exactly is "I can go from the start to the finish using another path" a problem?   Note also, that in either route, both premises are required.
$$\begin{array}{|l}~~1.~~ P\\~~2.~\neg P\\\hline~~3.~~ P\vee Q\quad\text{disjunction, 1} \\~~4.~~Q\qquad\text{disj. syllogism, 2, 3}\end{array}\qquad\begin{array}{|l}~~1.~~ P\\~~2.~\neg P\\\hline~~3.~\neg P\vee Q\quad\text{disjunction, 2} \\~~4.~~Q\qquad\text{disj. syllogism, 1, 3}\end{array}$$


which would make the implication true whenever ¬P, not only when P
is a contradiction.


$P$ and $\neg P$ being simultaneously true is the contradiction.

I think your main confusion is that you seem to think that explosion only works when you have a contradictory proposition $P$. Note if $P$ is logically inconsistent, then $P \to Q$ is valid. This is a result of the principle of explosion. That is, we already have $\neg P$ as a logical truth, which means that if P were to also be true, then anything else would have to be true. The conjunction of two contradictory statements is always false, which is why a contradiction always implies anything.
In summary, it is not the case that you need $P$ to be contradictory in order for $(P \land \neg P)$ to be sufficient for any proposition, but if $P$ is contradictory, then $P \to Q$ is true.

The principle of explosion says that, for any $P$ and $Q$, $(P\land\neg P)\to Q$, right? Now, if I use the truth table of $\to$ I see that actually $A\to Q$ for any false proposition $A$. I don't think it's the case that any false proposition $A$ can be written as $B\land\neg B$ for some other proposition $B$.

@Elvis, is it not the case that for any $A$ it holds that $A \land (P \to P) \equiv A$?

Yes, it is. So?

@Elvis So, $A \land \neg A$ is saying the same thing as $\neg \top$ for any validity $\top$, e.g. $P \to P$.

That is not my concern. I'm asking whether it is true or not that, $A\to(\neg A\to B)$ for any $A$ and $B$. If so, how do you prove this not using truth tables? The proof Wikipedia provides only works when $\neg A$ is a contradiction, not any false statement.

That’s not what the proof is doing. It’s proving a different version of the principle of explosion, namely that if you have directly contradictory formulas on two lines, then you can infer anything. The version of the principle you mention can be seen as a result of the Deduction Theorem. That is, from $A,\neg A \vdash B$, we can infer $A \vdash \neg A \to B$.

you are making the mistake that you allready assume classical (two valued) logic,
logic is just more than that .
in some logics $\lnot P \to Q \equiv P \lor Q$ is just not true. and in some truthtables just don't exist (ituitionistic logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic for example)
your other point: what is a contradiction in the first place? it again depends on your logic, some logics have a special symbol ( $\bot$ ) as contradiction others just define it as $ P \land \neg P$
there are even logics where the principle of explosion doesnt hold ( Paraconsistent_logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic ) and then also the disjunctive syllogism doesn't hold ( the two are intimitly related)
so in short logic is much more extensive than what you allready know , enjoy it :)

It's not a dumb question. Every semester I give a proof of the principle of explosion. There's always at least one student who asks the question in your first bullet point. It comes from a natural and common misunderstanding of what logic about. Logic isn't about what's true. It's about how truth behaves (if we assume some propositions to be true). In other words, it can only tell us what follows from what. It doesn't tell us what to believe by itself. If we already know that some statements are true, then logic can tell us what follows from them. And, that's grounds for believing the statements that follow from them.
Your first bullet point:
The principle of explosion is also known as "Ex falso quodlibet". Latin for "From falsehood, anything [follows]". The English translation only refers to falsehood rather than contradiction. I'm guessing this motivates the question in your first bullet point. So, in the proof you've given, we don't know which of $P$ and $\neg P$ are true. (Logic doesn't tell us what's true). We only know that at least one of them is true and the other is false. (Because logic tells us how truth behaves). So, we cannot guarantee a falsehood from P alone (because that might be the true one). Similarly for $\neg P$.  Since we know that at least one is false, we guarantee a falsehood from their conjunction. That's a contradiction. So, your first bullet point if false. It does deal with any false statement. We just don't know which one it is. (Logic doesn't tell us what's true or false). But, when we know a statement is false, any statement follows from assuming it's true. That's because the negation of that statement is also true. So, when you assume a falsehood to be true, you are also implicitly assuming a contradiction to be true. That contradiction is the conjunction of the falsehood with its negation. I'll give an example of POE where we don't explicitly refer to the contradiction:
We know that "division by zero is possible" is a false proposition. Let's assume it's true. It follows that you are Batman. Consider the equation
$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x=0$.
Then, multiply both sides by zero. Apply the null factor law to the left hand side. Cancel the common factor on the right hand side. Then add one to each side:
\begin{align}
xy &= \frac{1}{x}x \\
0 &= 1 \\
1 &= 2
\end{align}
This is all allowed assuming that division by zero is possible. Now consider the set $S =\{e,b\}$ where $e$ denotes Elvis and $b$ denotes Batman. $S$ contains exactly $2$ elements. Since $2=1$, $S$ contains exactly $1$ element. Hence, $e$ and $b$ are duplicates. That is, $e=b$. But this says that Elvis is Batman.
See how we didn't explicitly refer the contradiction here? But arithmetic doesn't allow division by zero. So, the contradiction is implicit in our working.
Your second bullet point:
You are confusing the truth of $P\rightarrow Q$ with the truth of $Q$. It is not the case that $Q$ follows from $P$ being false. It's only the case that $P\rightarrow Q$ follows from $P$ being false. In other words, you cannot derive $Q$ from $\neg P$ and $P\rightarrow Q$. This is the fallacy of denying the antecedent.
I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you want me to clarify anything.


This proof specifically deals with contradictions, not any false
proposition

Continuing the proof by discharging the premise on line 2, we obtain the intermediate result:
(5) $~~\neg P \implies Q$
Discharging the premise on line 1, we obtain the the final result and theorem:
(6) $~~P \implies (\neg P \implies Q)$
This is actually the Principle of Vacuous Truth. Assuming $P$ is true, then $\neg P$ would be the false proposition you required.  Note that we cannot infer from this theorem that $Q$ is true.

The Principle of Explosion can be stated as follows:
For any logical propositions $P$ and $Q$, we have:
$P \land \neg P \implies Q$
It can be proven, starting with a contradiction, as follows:
(1) $~~P \land \neg P~~~~~~~~~~~$ (Premise)
(2) $~~\neg Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ (Premise)
(3) $~~ P \land \neg P~~~~~~~~~~~$ (Reiterate, 1)
(4) $~~\neg \neg Q ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ (Discharge, 2)
(5) $~~ Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ (Elim $\neg\neg$, 4)
(6) $~~P \land \neg P \implies Q~~~~~~~~$ (Discharge, 1)
As above, we cannot infer from this theorem that $Q$ is true.
